# EXCEL from input using formulas / arrays?

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

[EXCEL question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eonne.jpg)

The sample data is on the left -> how to achieve the expected result using excel?

[image]

Comment: Why is the link to the graphic not showing as embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula used to

<kbd>**I5**</kbd> cell `=UNIQUE(B5:B15)`

<kbd>**J5**</kbd> cell `=@SORT(FILTER(FILTER($C$5:$F$15,$B$5:$B$15=$I5,""),$J$4:$M$4=J$4,""),1,-1)`

Then drag down and across till need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I wrapped the formula in an IF statement to get rid of the zeros

=@IF(SORT(FILTER(FILTER($C$5:$F$15,$B$5:$B$15=$I21,""),$J$20:$M$20=J$20,""),1,-1)=0,"",SORT(FILTER(FILTER($C$5:$F$15,$B$5:$B$15=$I21,""),$J$20:$M$20=J$20,""),1,-1))